# Please help with this Discrete fourier transform question

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, computational-mathematics

Consider the ODE $\frac {d^2u}{dx^2} + 2\pi\frac {du}{dx} + \frac 54\pi^2u = g(x)$

where g is a periodic fuction with period 1 given by $g(x) = e^{\pi x}$ , $  0 \le x \lt 1$.

It is desired to find the steady state solution (ie the periodic solution with period 1) of this equation.

Briefly explain how you would use a discrete Fourier transform to solve this problem, and derive an explicit forumla for the discrete Fourier coefficients of u in this case.

I've found the relation $F[u](n) = \frac{F[u''](n)}{-4\pi^2n^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** with the notation $F[u](n)$ for the $n^t{}^h$ Fourier coefficient,
you get $$
F[u'](n) = 2i\pi n F[u](n) 
$$ via an integration by parts.\

---

proof:
$$
F[u'](n) = \int_0^1 u'(t) e^{-2i\pi n t }dt
= [u(t) e^{-2i\pi n t }]_0^1 - \int_0^1 u(t)
(-2i\pi n e^{-2i\pi n t })dt
$$Here, the $[.]_0^1$ part is $0 $ because of periodicity.
It remains:

$$
F[u'](n) = 2i\pi n \int_0^1 u(t)e^{-2i\pi n t }dt
= 2i\pi n F[u](n)
$$

Comment: Hi mookid, thanks for the reply. Could you explain how you came to that? I'm having some trouble understanding this topic.

Comment: I detailed the proof. For the remaining part, apply twice the result and you get a relation between Fourier coefficients of $g$ and $u$.

Comment: I've updated my question with the relation that I think you were getting at - is that the relation you meant?  Also would I be right in saying that the solution of u is then obtained by applying the inverse DFT?

Comment: @Dany yes, and yes.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.